# Advanced software for OEIS?

Tags: soft-question, sequences-and-series, oeis, software

Is there (if not, why?) a software where I can input a sequence of integers, like into the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), and then it makes some simple transformations on it to check whether the sequence can be obtained from some other sequence(s)?

For example, if I enter 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, then currently OEIS returns A005843: The nonnegative even numbers (which starts with 0, but OEIS can search for subsequences).
But suppose that A005843 is not in the database yet.
Then OEIS will not return anything.
Instead, a more intelligent search software could return A000027: The positive integers.

I know that this raises several questions, like what transformations, which sequences to display first etc., but the feature could be quite useful.
Even better, if the software could do more complicated things, like check whether my sequence is the sum of two OEIS entries.

ps. My motivation came from the sequence 2, 4, 9, 16, 27, 38 currently missing from OEIS, which was posed on [this Hungarian puzzle page](https://qubit.hu/2018/03/05/esz-ventura-egy-egyszeruen-indulo-sorozat-ami-tenyleg-roppant-egyszeru).
(The puzzle has already expired, so feel free to discuss.)

Comment: The whole point is to decide what is the meaning of "simple transformations".

Comment: @YCor The whole point of what?

Comment: If you make an algorithm for something one general rule is to decide what the algorithm computes, isn't it? Here the input would be a few terms of a sequence, and the output would be the set of sequences "simply related by some mathematical rule" to the sequence. We can agree that there's no way to formally define this. Still, I agree that there are some most obvious transformations which we can stick with, but even this is not so obvious... (1) passing from $(u_n)$ to $(au_n+b)$; (b) passing from $(u_n)$ to $(u_{an+b})$ (which is not reversible)? more things allowed?

Comment: also remember that "input a sequence" is quite vague. I can see  three options: (a) you input the OEIS number of a classified sequence, (b) input a finite sequence of integers with commas (c) input a finite sequence of integers without commas. (b)/(c) is the normal OEIS input to recognize sequences, according to whether one considers ordered sequences.

Comment: In what way is "the positive integers" an intelligent return for the even positive integers? Oh, and are you familiar with the "superseeker" option at OEIS?

Comment: @Gerry Do you want to convert this into an answer?

Comment: @Gerry Oh, and in reply to your 1st question, see T003 here: https://oeis.org/superhelp.txt

Comment: @GerryMyerson in what way is "(n!)" an intelligent return for "(2n!)"?. Thanks a lot for your input. I now have a definition for "simple transformation": *A simple transformation is a transformation which is not only simple but intelligent. Example: a non-intelligent output for a input sequence $(u_n)$ is a known sequence $(v_n)$ such that $v_{2n}=u_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @YCor (and OP), rethinking my comment, if all the software returns is "the positive integers" then I wouldn't consider that to be intelligent. But if it returns "dividing your sequence by the common factor 2, we get the positive integers," that I would consider to be intelligent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok now I see what you mean. Indeed it's a good idea that the software describes the relation between the output sequences and the original one. I don't think it's the main issue: once I set up a rule of allowable rules I can certainly check and tell which rules I used. The issue is rather which rules are allowable. For instance we can restrict or not to individual sequences. The algo checks all classified sequences, computes a set of related sequences and tries detects the input. Allowing pairs one has to start with all pairs of classified sequences...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There has been some previous discussion on the [OEIS mailing list](http://list.seqfan.eu/pipermail/seqfan/) about similar topics. For instance, about [the sum of two sequences](http://list.seqfan.eu/pipermail/seqfan/2015-July/015023.html). (If I recall correctly, there was a university project that performed a more in depth search to find new combinations for existing sequences, but I can't seem to find the details now...).

For more of an answer to your question, I would check out this thread: http://list.seqfan.eu/pipermail/seqfan/2015-February/014455.html where a user links to [some code (on github)](https://github.com/p-e-w/sequencer) which is currently implemented on a website http://www.sequenceboss.org/ (was a bit slow on first load for me).

Plugging in the above numbers gives me:

---

Result
SequenceBoss thinks the sequence

$$(a_n)_{n≥1}=2,4,9,16,27,38,…$$
is generated by

$$a_n=(−1+n)^2+\text{prime}(n)$$
If true, the sequence continues

$$2,4,9,16,27,38,53,68,87,110,131,…$$

http://sequenceboss.org/?q=2%2C+4%2C+9%2C+16%2C+27%2C+38

Answer (score 23):

There is a ["superseeker" option](http://oeis.org/ol.html) at OEIS which does something like what you are asking for.

Comment: "The second server, Superseeker, does not just look up the sequence in the OEIS, it will also apply a large number of algorithms in order to attempt to explain the sequence. Send a message to
superseeker@oeis.org
containing a line like
[lookup 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31]
(with no Subject line).  The program will try VERY hard to find an explanation. Only one request may be submitted at a time, and (since this program does some serious computing), only one request per user per hour please. If there is no lookup line you will receive the help file for Superseeker".

Comment: Btw, the superseeker couldn't figure out the (in hindsight) rather simple rule for the sequence 2, 4, 9, 16, 27, 38.

Comment: @domotorp I can't guess either the simple rule for this little sequence. We have $(2,4,9,16,27,38)=(1,4,9,16,25,36)+(1,0,0,0,2,2)$. What do you want to do with $(1,0,0,0,2,2)$???

Comment: @YCor: Yeah, I can't figure it out either. I did notice that the first five elements are small powers of 2 and 3, but then 38 has me stumped.

Comment: The solution is already given in BurnsBA's answer.

Comment: AFAIK Superseeker looks for ways to transform the sequence to an OEIS sequence, but doesn't try for combinations of two sequences.  Note that with about $300000$ sequences in the OEIS there would be about $45$ billion possibilities for a sum of two sequences, rather a lot to search.

Comment: @YCor, funny, it looks like you had an off-by-one error – instead of $(1,4,9,16,25,36)$ it wanted $(0,1,4,9,16,25)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK I see. Anyway $(2,3,5,7,11,13)$ has plenty of occurrences, through $(1,2,4,6,10,12)$ or $(0,1,3,5,9,11)$ which appear in zillions of OEISs. Anyway one could add 10 more terms and narrow the set of solutions.

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps worth mentioning here [Sagemath's functionality](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/databases/sage/databases/oeis.html) to communicate with OEIS. ([Sagemath](http://sagemath.org) is basically a large Python library).

Apart from searching, one can retrieve components of records, etc etc.

Another way to interact with OEIS in Sagemath is via [FindStat](http://www.findstat.org/),
see [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/databases/sage/databases/findstat.html).

There is also a [Haskell package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/oeis) with similar functionality.

Comment: [GFun for Sage](http://www.luschny.de/math/seq/gfun/gfun.html) also interacts with OEIS.

Answer (score 2):

This should be useful
https://sequencedb.net/
looks pretty sharp to me.
Sequences are longer than on OEIS.